# Insert a Controller function into a View with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

I want to return the result of my function into my View using a Route.
This is my Controller

```
class AnnonceController extends Controller
{
     public function annonceAffiche() {
         $data = Annonce::select('titre', 'description', 'prix')->get()->toJson();
         return $data;
     }
}
```

My View

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        <h1>Liste</h1>

    </div>
</body>
```

My current route

```
Route::get('/annonces', function() {
    return view('annonces', [
        'uses' => 'AnnonceController@annonceAffiche'
        ]);
});
```

However it only shows my View and not the result of my Controller.
When I change my route for this one, I see the results

```
Route::get('/annonces', [
'uses' => 'AnnonceController@annonceAffiche'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the follwing

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AnnonceController;
Route::get('/annonces', function(AnnonceController $ctl) {
    return view('annonces', ['data' => $ctl->annonceAffiche()]);
});
```

Or via [Real Time Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/facades#real-time-facades)

```
use Facades\App\Http\Controllers\AnnonceController;
Route::get('/annonces', function() {
   return view('annonces', ['data' => AnnonceController::annonceAffiche()]);
});
```

Comment: Same result as before, I have the view but not the annonceAfficher() results

Comment: Sure, added it !

Comment: I can't see any variables in your blade file !

Answer (score 0):

This is easy way for you

```
return redirect()->route('annonces', $data)
```

And your route look like this

```
Route::get('/{data}', 'AnnonceController@annonceAffiche')->name('annonces')
```